# Should we also close DB's .Prepare() in Golang?

Tags: sql, go, prepared-statement

From [this](https://github.com/mindreframer/golang-stuff/tree/master/github.com/VividCortex/go-database-sql-tutorial) tutorial shown that `rows.Closed()` must be called where `rows` is from `stmt.Query()`, is `stmt.Closed()` also should be called where `stmt` is from `db.Prepare()`?

```
// inside a function
stmt, err := db.Prepare(cmd) // cmd is SQL string
Check(err)
// should we add: defer stmt.Close()
rows, err := stmt.Query(params) // params is map/interface{}
defer rows.Close()
Check(err)
```

Comment: The answer is **YES**. I forget to close the statements and the `too many open tables` error occurred while I was accessing the Access DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is Yes. You should call stmt.Close();

The long answer can be found [in this google groups thread.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/ISh22XXze-s)

Comment: the link seems to have expired. This is why copy/paste is preferred over just adding a link.

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows

```
// inside a function
stmt, err := db.Prepare(cmd) // cmd is SQL string
if err != nil {
    println(err.Error())
}
defer stmt.Close()
rows, err := stmt.Query(params) // params is map/interface{}

if err != nil {
    println(err.Error())
}
```

Comment: but what if you are inserting a stuff in a loop would happen then ?